# Selecting x amount of items from a for each loop in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I dont know if this is possible, but im trying to get pagination from a `get_pages()` [function of Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) since i need those pages being echo with different classes or inside some div so I can manage them with Javascript later to match the desire template.

So far I have this to echo the content:

```
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');
            $i =0;
            foreach($pages as $page)
            {
                $content = $page->post_content;
                if(!$content)
                    continue;
                $i++;
                $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                $doc->loadHTML($content);
                $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
                $imagesrc = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
                $imagehref = $xpath->evaluate("string(//a/@href)");

                for($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i+=5) {
                    echo "<li><a id='item-$i' href='$imagehref'><img src='$imagesrc'/></a></li>\n";
                    for($i = 5; $i < count($content); $i+=18) {
                        echo "more";
                    }
                }
```

So right now i do get all items no matter if there is 10 or 50, but what i want it is to put them in blocks of 8, is that possible to do inside a for each? or there is another way to do it?

**Note** *I need to plit large set of posts into blocks of 8*

any help will be really **appreciated** 
thanks :)

Comment: I tried to answer this based on what I thought you were asking, but looking at your code again I'm wondering what the purpose of the two for loops at the bottom is.  Could you elaborate on why you're counting by 5 then by 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @aelfric5578's answer is to use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to break the array into the pieces you need. You could break the original `$pages` array or generate an array in the `foreach` and break that, whichever works best for you but I'd probably break the `$pages` array. Here is an example using the original `$pages`.

```
$blocks = array_chunk($pages, 8);
```

The benefit is going to be readability and maintainability. Since you already have an iterator-- and maybe should have maybe two, you seem to be using the same variable name twice-- it could get confusing to add more counters.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate counter.  Since you already have `$i` you can use a conditional and the modulo operator.  `$i % 8` returns zero if `$i` is divisible by 8 and the remainder of that division otherwise.

So, if `$i % 8 == 0`, start your grouping.  Assuming you plan on grouping things with a `<div>` or something like that.  You can close your grouping after `$i % 8 == 7` at the end of your for loop.

However, it seems you're setting `$i` twice.  Is there a reason for this?  For my solution to work, you would need to use a different variable for the inner for loop.